# Binding fails when used inside MenuItem.Icon

Tags: wpf, binding, contextmenu

I want to offer a context menu with an item that has a color swatch in the space where "icons" are normally placed for such menu items, i.e. the space corresponding to MenuItem.Icon.

But the color swatch is dynamic--a Brush property on the UserControl that (in this crafted example) changes to a random color in response to the ContextMenuOpening event--and my attempt at binding to it is failing.

When run, the menu item has no content in the Icon space, and Visual Studio's output contains an error that doesn't seem like it ought to be happening.

`System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.ContextMenu', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=PlacementTarget.RandomBrush; DataItem=null; target element is 'Rectangle' (Name=''); target property is 'Fill' (type 'Brush')`

Here's the XAML for the control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ContextMenuItemIconTest.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<UserControl.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu>
        <MenuItem Header="Do something">
            <MenuItem.Icon>
                <Rectangle Width="16" Height="16" Fill="{Binding PlacementTarget.RandomBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}" />
            </MenuItem.Icon>
        </MenuItem>
    </ContextMenu>
</UserControl.ContextMenu>
<Grid>

</Grid>
```

And the code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace ContextMenuItemIconTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for UserControl1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ContextMenuOpening += UserControl1_ContextMenuOpening;
        }

        void UserControl1_ContextMenuOpening(object sender, ContextMenuEventArgs e)
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            RandomBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb((byte)r.Next(256), (byte)r.Next(256), (byte)r.Next(256)));
        }

        #region RandomBrush (Dependency Property)
        public Brush RandomBrush
        {
            get { return (Brush)GetValue(RandomBrushProperty); }
            set { SetValue(RandomBrushProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty RandomBrushProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
                "RandomBrush",
                typeof(Brush),
                typeof(UserControl1),
                new PropertyMetadata(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue)));
        #endregion


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a better solution but I think the scenario here is very tricky. The `Icon` content seems to be detached completely from the visual tree. So you cannot use Binding with `RelativeSource` or `ElementName` and strangely even setting the `Source` to some `{x:Reference}` causes some cyclic reference error.

I just could think of this work-around, a little hacky but it's acceptable. There is an interesting knowledge about the `Freezable` object. Binding inside it (set for some property) can use `RelativeSource` as well as `ElementName` even when it's just declared as a resource (added to `Resources`). So in this case we can try using some object deriving from `Freezable` to act as the proxy. Because this proxy is declared as a resource, we can set the `Binding` inside `Icon` with `Source` being set to some StaticResource referencing the proxy. Then it would work. There are many objects deriving from `Freezable` for your choice, you can even create your own class. But I would like to use something existing here. The `DiscreteObjectKeyFrame` is the most suitable object to use. Technically its `Value` property can hold any kind of object. Now's the working code:

```
<ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu.Resources>
       <!-- the proxy here -->
       <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame x:Key="o" KeyTime="0" 
                   Value="{Binding PlacementTarget.RandomBrush, 
                   RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"/>
    </ContextMenu.Resources>

    <MenuItem Header="Do something">
        <MenuItem.Icon>
            <Rectangle Width="16" Height="16" 
                       Fill="{Binding Value, Source={StaticResource o}}" />
        </MenuItem.Icon>
    </MenuItem>
</ContextMenu>
```